# selecting the last element of an array separated by comma

Tags: arrays, bash

How can I get the last element of an array separated by comma in bash?

```
[8.5, 7.7, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 7.4, 8.4, 9.6, 10.7, 11.4, 12.5, 13.2, 14.2, 14.8, 15.8, 16.5]
```

If the array is called `$temp`, if I type in the terminal

```
echo ${temp[@]:(-1)}
```

I get number `5`.

Fedorqui, I have something wrong...I get the same

```
[enric@localhost ]$ echo $temp
```

(8.5, 7.7, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 7.4, 8.4, 9.6, 10.7, 11.4, 12.5, 13.2, 14.2, 14.8, 15.8, 16.5, 17.3)

```
[enric@localhost ]$ echo ${temp[${#temp[@]}-1]}
```

(8.5, 7.7, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 7.4, 8.4, 9.6, 10.7, 11.4, 12.5, 13.2, 14.2, 14.8, 15.8, 16.5, 17.3)

Comment: do not address to me in the question because I cannot see it (I discovered it by chance). Update the question showing exactly how you define `$temp` and address me through comments.

Comment: so what did you end up doing? Update your question or comment in [my] answer to make sure this gets closed.

Answer (score 4):

### Something quite straightforward (credits to Tom Fenech)

```
${array[@]: -1}
```

On newer version of bash, you can also just use a negative index, as explained in [access last but element of bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306054/access-last-but-element-of-bash-array/29306190#29306190):

```
${array[-1]}
```

### With some arithmetic

Use:

```
${array[${#array[@]}-1]}
```

See:

```
$ array=(8.5, 7.7, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.4, 5.2, 5.1, 5.5, 7.4, 8.4, 9.6, 10.7, 11.4, 12.5, 13.2, 14.2, 14.8, 15.8, 16.5)
$ echo ${array[${#array[@]}-1]}
16.5
```

- `${#array[@]}` gives the length of the array.
- We decrement the value in one since the first element is the 0st.
- Then we access to that given position, say `v`, with `${array[v]}`.

All together it becomes `${array[${#array[@]}-1]}`.

Note in bash the arrays are not comma separated, but space separated. Also, we define them with `()`, not `[]`. If you happen to have a string with comma separated values, then it is just a matter of using `awk` for example:

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' <<< "$string"
```

Comment: No need for the arithmetic, you can just use a slice: `"${array[@]: -1}"` - On newer version of bash, you can also just use a negative index `"${array[-1]}"`, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29306190/2088135).

Comment: Fantastic, I wasn't aware of this way of doing it. This makes the answer totally new, I updated it accordingly. Many thanks @TomFenech :)